# I have a AD9833 function generator which has the ability to change frequency from 1k to 1MHz but a fixed 0.6V output I want 1V to 10V pk to pk

Tags: amplifier, opto-isolator, dds

The frequency changes from the AD9833 DDS chip but it has a 0.6V pk to pk and I need it to be 1V to 10V pk to pk this is my circuit so far the goal is to have an adjustable gain please any adjustments will be welcome.

[image]

Comment: Is the same circuit as the other question [Adding programmable amplitude control to an AD9833-based function generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/703831/101063)?

Comment: that was 5V pk to pk the concept is similar

Comment: the title does not  describe the question ... please correct it

Comment: what is the problem with the circuit?  ... please add the description to your post

Comment: done, well the second stage with the LM318 has the isolated variable resistor connected to it from the NSL-32SR3 but whenever I change the resistance the output is never amplified

Comment: @zug - You can't have this new question *and* change your [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/703831) to be asking the same thing. That causes duplication of effort. || I will reverse your previous question to the state when it was answered. Please consider whether you can [áccept](/help/someone-answers) the answer you got to *that* question. || In any case, if that question is no longer relevant to you then please *edit that question*, to make it clear that you don't need more help there.

Comment: @ChesterGillon - Hi, FYI I have reverted that previous question back to the state when it was answered, to prevent it becoming a "chameleon question". This question is now a different circuit to that previous one.

Comment: "but whenever I change the resistance the output is never amplified" - how did you check that the opto-resistor changes its value? How well to you control the LED current?

Comment: I tested the physical circuit also I've noticed the current may be too hight so I may have to change the R7 resistor.

Answer (score 1):

You have an inverting amplifier in your design, with R16 = 3.9k .
To get a gain above 1 you will need the feedback (optoresistor) value bigger than 3.9k. However, if you [check the datasheet for NSL-32SR3](https://mm.digikey.com/Volume0/opasdata/d220001/medias/docus/1088/NSL-32SR3.pdf), you will find out that even at 0.1mA of input current the photoresistor has the value of about 2k, and no manufacturing data below that are provided,
[image]

I would expect that if you reduce R16 to 100R and manage to control the LED current from 2mA down to 0.1mA, you will see some amplification.

Also note that you will need somewhat higher supply voltage to get 10V amplitudes out of it. The standard voltage is usually +-15V, not 10.